# Relation between Admin and Item (Class Diagram)

Tags: uml, aggregation, class-diagram, inventory-management

What relationships should be there between:

1. Admin and Employee (Admin registers / edits employee)
2. Admin and Item (Admin creates / deletes / updates item)
3. Item and Order_Item (Order_Item uses data from Item)
4. Task and Order (Each order has at most two tasks)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting start.  In addition to [Axel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72416338/3723423) answer, and considering your revised diagram, I'd like to provide you some means to find issues by yourself:

1. **Cross-check systematically all the multiplicities**.  You do this by first imagining an instance on one side an see with how many instances it can be associated with on the opposite side, and then do the same in the opposite direction.

   Take the example of `Item` and `Order_item`:  take an order item, it is clear that it must refer to an item and can only be associated with one item.  So `1` (which is equivalent to `1..1`) is correct.  But in the opposite direction: are you sure that an `Item` can be ordered only once?  That there can be at most a single order_item?
2. **Make sure that optional associations are optional**.  So cross check multiplicities with a minimum cardinality greater than 0 correspond to mandatory associations.

   Take again the example of `Item` and `Order_item`: the admin can create a new `Item` X, that is not used in any order item until it is ordered a first time.  So there seem nothing wrong for an `Item` to appear in 0 `Order_item`.

   Take another example:  Wouldn't  "at most 2 tasks" mean `0..2`?  Or are you sure that each order must have at least one task? Only you could answer ;-)
3. **Be extra-careful with any relation that are not simple associations**. The question here is simple:  if you would replace your special relationship with a simple assiciation,  would you loose some critical information in your diagram?

   Take the example of the black diamond:  ok,  if you'd remove it,  you would loose the hint that an order item makes no sense without the order to which it belongs and has no reason to exist on its own. You can keep it.

   But what about the white diamonds. If you would remove them, would you really lose any relevant meaning that is vital for the designer to know?

   You've already removed the inheritance (withe triangular arrow head) and that's fine.  Because this means that an instance on the side of the arrow head could be used whenever an instance of the side of the arrow head is expected.
4. **Subsidiary question**:  do any classes in the diagram share a significant set of attributes and behavior? If yes, you can ask yourself is one isn't a specialization of the other (inheritance).

   For example, is an `Admin` also an `Employee`?  If yes, you may add an inheritance relation between the two, and remove in `Admin` what is already defined in the employee.

Comment: Hmm. Shouldn't that be the place for answers rather than questions? SO isn't meant for code reviews. The above design is just flawed. Admin **is** the Inventory which is either wrong wording or wrong concepts. Both wrong. It's not possible to teach that here even with the best questions you might come up.

Comment: @qwerty_so I think the diagram was updated and no longer has an inheritance.  On the questions vs answers, you have a point but I believe that these questions are of a more general value than the review/correction of a specific class diagram ;-)

Comment: @AdilAhmed Well, ask a question and you get an answer. But at which quality? That clearly depends on the question itself. Does it provide enough context to come to some conclusion? Your question doesn't provide that. So one can't give an answer - or any answer. And that won't help anybody. Neither you nor any other person coming across this post. I'm not toxic, just realistic.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is hard to tell from what info you give us. Maybe you want to capture which instance of an admin created an item. Then you should name the association end `creator`. That an admin manages all classes doesn‘t mean that the admin class must have associations.

An `order item` references an `item`, so, there should be an association instead of a generalization.

All the rest of the shown relationships should be regular associations. The white diamond you use denotes a shared aggregation and is almost always superfluous and only confuses the readers.

All associations should have multiplicities and could have role names at their ends, which would make the diagram much more meaningful.

Comment: Check the updated diagram if it looks good. There is only one admin. I just want to show that admin controls Items in inventory.

Comment: As it is, the Admin _is_ the inventory.